Finding the point of maximum curvature on an exponential
I am trying to estimate the point of maximum curvature along an exponential decay function.
A little background: I am working with raw mass spectrometry data measuring helium-4 using a helium-3 spike gas. What I am trying to measure and correct for is beam suppression, wherein a high sample gas volume suppresses the intensity measurements of the spike gas.
Beam suppression looks like this: beyond a certain 4 amu threshold, 3 amu intensities begin to drop. The best-fit line is provided by $y=a - b e^{x}$. The ultimate goal here is to correct/normalize beam suppressed data to provide a simple outlier detection algorithm. I can't provide that outlier detection without this correction, as otherwise the scatter of legitimate measurements is too wide to be of any use.
I want to measure the point at which those intensities begin to drop, which it seems to me is that point of maximum curvature, or somewhere just beyond it. Following similar posts on this website, I then calculate:
$$
y' = be^{x} \\ 
y'' = be^{x} \\ 
\kappa = \frac{y''}{\left(1 + y'^2\right)^{3/2}} = \frac{be^x}{
\left(
1 + (be^x)^2
\right)^{3/2}
}
$$
The problem I'm facing is that this always returns the curvature at the last datum, I assume because as an exponential function, the curvature is always increasing.
So, perhaps I am not calculating the correct thing? Or perhaps the scale of the data is playing a role that I'm not accounting for?
Is there a way to find the point along the curve that I'm looking for mathematically?

Are you sure that the best fit equation you have given is correct? A constant plus an increasing exponential doesn't seem to resemble the graph you have linked to. I may be wrong.

It's an exponential decay, where b is negative. I'll update the post accordingly.

The derivative of the curvature is
$$
\frac{b\,e^x}{1+b^2e^{2x}}\,(1-2b^2e^{2x})
$$
So, if $b<0$ and $2b^2<1,$ the curvature is increasing up to the point  where $1-b^2e^{2x}=0$ and then decreasing. So the point of maximum curvature is $x=\tfrac{1}{2}\ln(1/b^2)$

Let me know if this is not clear and I will add some more details.
